# Moshi Multiple Custom Names

Tags: java, android, kotlin, moshi

With Moshi you can have a custom name for a field of a class

```
@Json(name = "your name") string name
```

But can you have more than one custom name?

```
@Json(name = "your name" || "your/name" || "your-name") string name,
```

So either one of  `"your name"`  or `"your/name"` or `"your-name"` would match?

Answer (score 5):

Moshi doesn't support this feature. If you need it, declare multiple fields of various names (`yourName1`, `yourName2`, etc.). It’s more annoying but the code’s really obvious.

Comment: Still not supported?

Comment: Still not supported?